# Return just the elements of an array, without the square brackets Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, instance-methods

I have an array that contains three words

```
three_words = ["if", "the", "printed"]
```

The words are in an instance method inside of a class, and I want it so that when I call the instance method on a test it prints out like :

```
"if the printed"
```

I tried adding the following to the method at the end, but when I call the instance method on a string it still returns ["if", "the", "printed"]

```
three_mcwords.each do |word|
  word + " " 
end
```

Comment: You were close... Change the `each` to a `map` and your code works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look for the method [`Array#join`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-join), as `three_mcwords.join(" ")`. But you called `Array#each`, which return the receiver (as per the *MRI* implementation), on which you called the method [`#each`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-each).

You called `three_mcwords.each do |word|..`. See here the receiver is `three_mcwords`, which holds the reference of the *array* `["if", "the", "printed"]`, thus when `each` block competed, you got the *array* `["if", "the", "printed"]` back.

Example :

```
['foo', 'bar'].each { |str| "hi" + str } # => ["foo", "bar"]
['foo', 'bar'].join(" ") # => "foo bar"
```

Both are working as they were implemented in *MRI*.

Comment: Sweet - that works. Do I need to permanently set three_mcwords = three_mcwords.join(" ") ?

Comment: You can put it back in the same variable like that, or some other variable, or whatever - it's up to you!

Comment: @modulus show your full method body with the class, I can advice then.